How can we find submodules of the tensor product.
So I was looking at the to following example. Consider the s.e.s.
$$
0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\iota} \mathbb{Q} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0
$$
with inclusion and projection. Then if we tensor this with $-\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ we loose injectivity of the map $id_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\otimes \iota$ since $\mathbb{Z}_2\otimes\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $\mathbb{Z}_2\otimes \mathbb{Q}=0$. This provides an example where $A\subset B$ does not imply $M\otimes A \subset M \otimes B$. However if M is flat then by left exactness and injective of any inclusion map the above implication holds (I think).

So having said that given a flat module M can we find all of the submodules of $M\otimes A$ in terms of the submodules of $A$ (and probably the submodules of M as well).

Also can we have have $A\subset B$, $M\otimes B\neq 0$ but still $M\otimes A$ not a submodule of $M\otimes B$.

For the first question, try to use the definition of tensor product to show that $M \otimes A \cong M$, then you'll see that submodules only depends on $M$, but not $A$

Here's an example for the second one: consider the inclusion $ \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ given by multiplication by $2$, and take $ M = \mathbb{Z}_2 $. Then $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, but the after tensoring the multiplication-by-two map becomes the zero map.

@RHspqr wait this holds for any flat module ?

@Bigalos In fact this holds for all modules, not only flat-modules

@smitke6 I think what you said proves that Z is not a flat Z module, when I say inclusion I mean $\iota :A\rightarrow B$ where $\iota(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$ for A a submodule, hence a subset of B

@RHspqr I think this holds when we are looking at $R\otimes_{R}M$ however not for two general R-modules A and M

@Bigalos smitke6's counterexample still holds actually, you may just consider $A= 2\mathbb{Z}, B=\mathbb{Z}$, then the method proposed still workds since $2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

To answer your first question, we may consider the $R=k$, a non-algebraically closed field and let $M=k[x]$, $A=k'$, where $k'$ is a finite field extension of $k$. It can be shown that $k' \otimes k[x] = k'[x]$, while $k[x] = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} kx^i$. For a finite k-submodule $V \subseteq k[x]$, let $f_1,...,f_n$ be a basis of $V$, notice that these are polynomials in one variable， and let $e_1,...,e_m$ be $k$-basis of $k'$, then it can be shown that $e_if_j,i\leq m,j \leq n$ is a basis of $V \otimes k'$. Next consider a polynomial $h = ax+a'$, where $a,a' \in k'-k$, then $k(ax+a')$ cannot be of form $V \otimes k'$, as desired.
For you second question, let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring and consider
$$0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m} \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow 0$$
Pass it by the functor $- \otimes A/\mathfrak{m}$ we get
$$ \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow 0 $$
If there's some problem with the solution, let me know.
